# Как написать уравнение на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, уравнения

Я хочу написать уравнение на python, которое будет выводить необходимое число.

Выглядит уравнение вот так:

```
y + 5x = z(x+1)
```

2 значения уже известны:

```
y = 3.62
z = 4.5
```

Но не известен **X**, который и нужно найти.

```
3.62 + 5x = 4.5(x+1)
#Потом он решает это уравнение и на вывод я должен получить: 1.76, которое запишу в переменную.
```

Как мне это сделать?

Comment: в чем именно проблема? неизвестно, как решить уравнение??

Comment: `y + 5x = z(x+1)` =>
`5x = zx + z - y` =>
`5x - zx = z - y` =>
`x(5 - z) = z - y |: (5 - z), где z != 5` =>
`x = (z - y)/(5 - z)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такой вариант, но с ходу он работает, если выражение приравнивается к нулю.
То есть мы `3.62 + 5x = 4.5(x+1)` приводим к `3.62 + 5x - 4.5(x+1)`
Предварительно устанавливаем `pip install sympy`

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol


x = Symbol('x')

r = solve(3.62 + 5*x - 4.5*(x+1), x)
print(r)
# [1.76000000000000]
```